# How to use SetSuspendState() api for hibernate or suspend in win32 sdk?

Tags: winapi

I have a problem in win32 sdk programming. My button click should initiate hibernate mode in windows. I searched
**SetSuspendState()**
API in msdn Where it takes three boolean parameters.

but using this API in Visual Studio 8 for win32 project results in following error

```
    Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SetSuspendState@12 referenced in function "long stdcall WndProc(struct HWND *,unsigned int,unsigned int,long)" (?WndProc@@YGJPAUHWND__@@IIJ@Z) button.obj sandy_win32_progs

    Error 2 fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals E:\Win32 SDK Progs sandy\sandy_win32_progs\Debug\sandy_win32_progs.exe sandy_win32_progs
```

any help would be welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa373201.aspx), you need to link with the `powrprof.lib` library. Add it to the list of libraries on the Linker tab in project properties.